# How to detect 404 in THEME file

Tags: theming, 8

I'd like to attach a library to a custom 404 page.  I'd like to do this in my theme file.  How can I know if the current response will be a 404 Page Not Found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

In your hook within your theme file:

```
  $status = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception');
  if ($status && $status->getStatusCode() == 404) {
    $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'themename/notfound';
  }
```